# Stata vs. R: Delta Method provides different results for relative risk SE's from logit model

Tags: r, stata, delta-method

I've been trying to estimate the conditional mean treatment effect of covariates in a logit regression (using relative-risk) along with their standard errors for inference purposes. The delta method is necessary to calculated the standard errors for these treatment effects. I've been trying to recreate these results using the Stata user written command, `adjrr`, to calculate the relative risk with standard errors and confidence intervals in R.

The `adjrr` command in Stata calculates the adjusted relative-risk (the conditional mean treatment effect of interest for my project) and it's SE's using the delta method. The `deltamethod` command in R should create the same results, however this is not the case.

How can I replicate the results from Stata in R?

I used the following self generated data: (https://migariane.github.io/DeltaMethodEpiTutorial.nb.html).

R code below:

```
generateData <- function(n, seed){
    set.seed(seed)
    age <- rnorm(n, 65, 5)
    age65p <- ifelse(age>=65, T, F)
    cmbd <- rbinom(n, size=1, prob = plogis(1 - 0.05 * age))
    Y <- rbinom(n, size=1, prob = plogis(1 - 0.02* age - 0.02 * cmbd))
    data.frame(Y, cmbd, age, age65p)
}

# Describing the data
data <- generateData(n = 1000, seed = 777) 
str(data)

logfit <- glm(Y ~ age65p + cmbd, data = data, family = binomial)
summary(logfit)

p1 <- predict(logfit, newdata = data.frame(age65p = T, cmbd = 0), type="response")
p0 <- predict(logfit, newdata = data.frame(age65p = F, cmbd = 0), type="response")
rr <- p1 / p0
rr

library(msm)
se_rr_delta <- deltamethod( ~(1 + exp(-x1)) / (1 + exp(-x1 -x2)), coef(logfit), vcov(logfit))
se_rr_delta
```

R Results:
[image: R Results]

Stata Code (using same data):

```
logit Y i.age65p i.cmbd

adjrr age65p
```

Stata Results:
[image: Stata Results]

Comment: Seems to be mainly about details of programming in Stata and R with not much revealed about relevance to statistics. And thus, I'd guess 'off topic' for this site. Can you say something about your data and objectives and why you're asking about 'relative risk' and 'SE'?

Comment: Could you explain what `adjrr` and `deltamethod` are supposed to be doing?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have edited my post to better address my question.

Comment: Does the STATA output show the SE or just confidence intervals?

Comment: The STATA SE is in the parentheses. In STATA, the ARR=0.8146, and the SE=0.0626.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `cmbd` variable to its mean when calculating the predicted probabilities? This gets me pretty close:

`car::deltaMethod(logfit, "(1 / (1 + exp(-(b1 + b2 + b3 * .089)))) / (1 / (1 + exp(-(b1 + b3 * .089))))", 
parameterNames = c("b1", "b2", "b3"))`

Comment: Interesting! I ran your code and got the results below (I"m still wondering why they aren't exact if the delta-method is being using in both situations): 
ARR=0.814238, SE=0.062702, 95% CI: [0.691344 0.9371)

Comment: @awhug- I found using your method with larger dataset and with many more covariates, the SE difference between Stata and R grows. I think Stata/R must be handling the covariates we are conditioning on in different ways?

Comment: Interesting. It's still happening when you're also setting those additional covariates to their mean as well? The reason I thought conditioning on the means might be the solution was because Norton, Miller & Kleinman (2013) say in Stata they hold "all other covariates (including the constant term) equal to their original values". I don't actually use Stata so I can't comment on why the discrepancies emerge. Sorry!

Comment: I know! It's very strange to me. I tried holding 'all other covariates' to both their means and their self-imposed reference states (for binary covariates) when using the delta method in R. Neither gives us the exact same solution as Stata.